# Laravel Select из 2х таблиц

Tags: laravel

Есть 2 таблицы: 
table1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 и table2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запросом получаю необходимые значения из `table1`:

```
$data = $this->db->table('table1')->select('name', 'number', 'date', 'txt')->where('imei', '5812375612387218747')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
```

У взаимосвязанных полей совпадает `rid`. Помогите модифицировать запрос, чтобы получать не только `'name', 'number', 'date', 'txt'`, но и имена файлов из `table2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь объединением таблиц:

```
$data = $this->db->table('table1')
    ->select('name', 'number', 'date', 'txt', 'filename')
    ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.rid', '=', 'table2.rid')
    ->where('imei', '5812375612387218747')
    ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Сейчас начал читать про отношения в моделях один ко многим, интересно есть ли в этом методе преимущество перед вашим?

Comment: Нет, отношения в данном случае прописывать не нужно. Если вы хотите это реализовать через отношения, то это совсем другая история).

Comment: К сожаления данный метод не подходит. Необходимо использование отношений один ко многим!